# Not displaying Inmobi ads

Tags: ios, ads, inmobi

I added the app store URL in the app. But I want to test the ads in my device from xcode. Ads are getting loaded but not getting displayed on screen. I am in India, is this place specific problem or Inmobi dont provide ads for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Did you added it to the screen as a subview?

```
inmobiAdView = [[IMAdView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50) imAppId:INMOBI_APP_ID imAdSize:IM_UNIT_320x50];
inmobiAdView.delegate = self;

IMAdRequest *request = [IMAdRequest request];
/**
 * additional targeting parameters. these are optional
 */
request.gender = kIMGenderMale;
request.education = kIMEducationBachelorsDegree;
// etc ..
inmobiAdView.imAdRequest = request;
[self.view addSubview:inmobiAdView];  // Did you added this line? this line add the adView as a subview
[inmobiAdView loadIMAdRequest];
```